# Extending AngularJS with jQuery like plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-plugins, angularjs-directive

I am creating an AngularJS directive that would bind to a property on the controller scope which contains an 'htm'l string. The string is pulled from a database on the backend. I wish to append the html to an element which contains the directive attribute. Afterwards I would like to drill into the newly created element and surround each 'word' with a span. I have achieved the latter using a jQuery extension function similar to the jQuery highlight plugin. In fact my code is a modification of the original code for this plugin:

```
jQuery.extend({
highlight: function (node, re) {
    if (node.nodeType === 3) {
        var match = node.data.match(re);
        if (match) {
            var highlight = document.createElement('span');               
            highlight.className = 'highlight';
            var wordNode = node.splitText(match.index);
            wordNode.splitText(match[0].length);
            var wordClone = wordNode.cloneNode(true);
            highlight.appendChild(wordClone);             
            wordNode.parentNode.replaceChild(highlight, wordNode);
            return 1; //skip added node in parent
        }
    } else if ((node.nodeType === 1 && node.childNodes) && // only element nodes that have children
            !/(script|style)/i.test(node.tagName) && // ignore script and style nodes
            !(node.tagName === 'SPAN' && node.hasAttribute('ng-class'))) { // skip if already highlighted
        for (var i = 0; i < node.childNodes.length; i++) {
            i += jQuery.highlight(node.childNodes[i], re);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
});

jQuery.fn.highlight = function (times) {
  var pattern = "\\b([^ ]+)\\b";
  var re = new RegExp(pattern);
  return this.each(function () {
    jQuery.highlight(this, re);
 });
};
```

The code for my directive:

```
.directive('spanner', function($compile){
var linkFn = function(scope, element)
{
   element.append(scope.spanner);
   element.highlight();
   $compile(element.contents())(scope);
};

return {
    scope: {
        spanner: '='
    },
    restrict: 'A',
    link: linkFn
  };  
});
```

This works fine but I am using jQuery. I would prefer to extend jQlite which ships with AngularJs (or perhaps do it in a way which requires no extension at all!). I tried to extend jQlite but failed each time. Can someone suggest a way I can do this without relying on jQuery? I think this would substantially improve my understanding of AngularJs. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since 90% of the plugin is native script it's a fairly simple port into a directive with no library (jQuery or jQlite) dependencies:

```
app.directive('highlight', function() {
  /* define highligher variables and function */
  var pattern = "\\b([^ ]+)\\b";
  var re = new RegExp(pattern);

  var highlighter = function(node, re) {
    if (node.nodeType === 3) {
      var match = node.data.match(re);
      if (match) {
        var highlight = document.createElement('span');
        highlight.className = 'highlight';
        var wordNode = node.splitText(match.index);
        wordNode.splitText(match[0].length);
        var wordClone = wordNode.cloneNode(true);
        highlight.appendChild(wordClone);
        wordNode.parentNode.replaceChild(highlight, wordNode);
        return 1; //skip added node in parent
      }
    } else if ((node.nodeType === 1 && node.childNodes) && // only element nodes that have children
      !/(script|style)/i.test(node.tagName) && // ignore script and style nodes
      !(node.tagName === 'SPAN' && node.hasAttribute('ng-class'))) { // skip if already highlighted
      for (var i = 0; i < node.childNodes.length; i++) {
        i += highlighter(node.childNodes[i], re);
      }
    }
    return 0;
  }

   /* return directive link function */    
   return function(scope, elem) {
      /* initalize on element */
      highlighter(elem[0], re);
    }    

});
```

HTML

```
 <p highlight>Far far away</p>
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/QfutGcLIdIVXtJe0NvCF?p=preview)**</kbd>

Comment: Thank you! This is amazing! It really validates the Angular way of doing DOM manipulations! I am truly grateful! God bless!

Comment: could even put the function into a factoryso it doesn't have to be declared for every element...then just inject that factory

Comment: That is certainly an efficient way to go about it. Thanks again!